# Set style of pie chart using Excel InterOp in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am working with Excel InterOp to dynamically create a pie chart with C#. I have the chart generating correctly, however I am running into a problem trying to set a style.

If I have the document open in  Microsoft Excel and click on the chart I can set a style by doing the following:

Click on the Chart -> Click on the Paintbrush Icon --> Style Tab --> Select a style.

The first style that comes up in the list is the one I want to use. It is referred to "Style 1" in Microsoft Excel. I have tried setting the ChartStyle property, but it does not do anything.

```
the.ChartStyle = 1;
```

I tried setting it to "Style 1", however this results in an exception being thrown with a message saying to only use integers.

Is there an integer value that equates to "Style 1"? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just as an aside... working with Interop is a pain. You'll find yourself more comfortable with a "full .NET" library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com), that is extremely fast and doesn't require any headache with unmanaged code and processes, object marshalling, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Style 1" has the integer value 201.

If you want to find which integer value is matching which style, you should record a macro while you are selecting a style with a mouse, and then check what is recorded in a macro.